# Basic bash redirection

Tags: linux, bash

I'm learning the basics of bash and I'm having a little trouble.

I'm trying to figure out a one line command for extracting tar files in the working directory, without using variables, backticks or the command separator.

Suppose my tar file is called "example" and it resides in the working directory

```
grep "example" | tar -xf
```

However this doesn't place the output of grep after the -xf flag. I've tried other combinations with various other programs like rev and cat, but I still can't seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `tar -xf example`?

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. What if I had 100 tar files with very long names in a directory. I wouldn't want to waste my time finding the name, type tar -xf, then paste it after it. Furthermore, what if I only wanted to extract tar files that were created today? This is why I'm trying to figure this out. I want to use a program to find a tar file based on specific criteria, it's name perhaps, like in my example, then pass the name of the file to tar with the flags -xf.

Comment: Here's all the tars in the last 24 hours: `find . -mtime -1 -exec tar -xf {} \;`

Here's all the tars matching a globbing expression: `find . -name 'example*' -exec tar -xf {} \;`

Comment: Ah, this works perfectly. It looks like find is the program to use! However, could you explain the purpose of {} \; after the -xf? Just for my complete understanding.

Comment: That there `{}` is the argument placeholder; it expands to the path of the thing found. The `\;` is to prevent the invoking shell from "eating" the semicolon so the `-exec` command can "see" it.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: Got it, thanks so much for taking the time to explain that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be able to achieve what you need:

```
cat *.tar | tar -xvf - -i
```

Replace `*.tar` with your selector.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware you could use the - symbol that way. Thanks!